# How to plot ranged bars in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have data having upper point and lower point data i.e. ranged data for 100 data points. How can I do it in R? Data Example:

```
Upper Y axis : 1260 1284 1296 1308 1320
Lower Y axis : 1272 1272 1284 1296 1308
      X axis : 1 2 3 4 5
```

Image example:

[image: Ranged bars]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using the error bar geom, which can be nice for ranges

```
library(ggplot2)
data.df <- data.frame(
Upper =c( 1260, 1284, 1296, 1308, 1320),
Lower =c( 1272, 1272, 1284, 1296, 1308)
)
data.df$x <- 1:nrow(data.df)
ggplot(data.df,aes(x=x,ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper))+geom_errorbar(width=.5)+theme_bw();
```

There's also a geom_rect for drawing rectangles (but it needs both width and height information)

Comment: not exactly.. but somewhat it solved the purpose. thank you